# How to change each list item front in a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-typeface

I am having 5 font styles (`Typeface`) and want to show user input 5 times into a `ListView` in different font style.
Below is my code I have tried.

```
 public void ShowTextStyles(String inputText, int color){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(EditImageActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.textstylelayout);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    // Array of strings...
    final String[] textStyles={"Gobold Bold.ttf","beyond_wonderland.ttf"};
    final String[] mobileArray = {inputText,inputText,inputText,inputText,inputText,inputText,inputText,inputText,inputText,inputText};
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EditImageActivity.this,
            R.layout.text_style_list, mobileArray);

    ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Set an item click listener for ListView
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Get the selected item text from ListView
            String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Display the selected item text on TextView




        }
    });
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom adapter and use it for your listview:

```
public class TestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> appData;
    String[] fontFiles = {"Gobold Bold.ttf", "beyond_wonderland.ttf"}; // add more fonts if wish more styles

public TestAdapter(Context context, List<String> appData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.appData = appData;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return appData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return appData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_item;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_app, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv_item = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv_item.setText(appData.get(position));
    Typeface typeface;

    // change this condition according to your need
    if (position == 0){
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontFiles[0]);
    }else {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontFiles[1]);
    }

    holder.tv_item.setTypeface(typeface);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank You soo much . It works perfectly.  One more thing , How could I acheve Onitem click listener ?     listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
            //Here you can get the position and access your 
            //TicketList Object
        }
    });     // it will work ?

Comment: yeah. Thank you for saving my day !

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to use `BaseAdapter`

```
public class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter {

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets(); 

    LayoutInflater lif;
    ImageView sideArrow;
    TextView tv;


    public Myadapter(Context ctx) {
        lif = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return favarets.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = lif.inflate(R.layout.inflate, null);
        sideArrow = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageViewsidemark);


        tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textFav);
        tv.setText(favarets.get(position));

        final Typeface tvFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "OPTIMA.TTF");
        tv.setTypeface(tvFont);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        return vi;
    }

}
```

> Here is the example how to use customAdapter
>   https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView

**Solution 2:**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filled_arr) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setTypeface(typeface);
            return view;
        }
    };
```

Comment: I am new in android and just not getting it inmy case what I have to do.

Comment: I am already using arrayadapter . so sould i replace that with base adapter

Comment: @farhan yes if you want to set each row different font then you need to use baseadapter..

Comment: @farhan please check my updated answer.we an set single font using arrayadapter.

Comment: getting an Error . void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference

Comment: i think getview is not working. its giving Null pointer exception